# Rails. Test validation of picture size

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

I have validation in my model, `validate :picture_size`, my model:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user

  default_scope -> { order(created_at: :desc) }

  mount_uploader :picture, PictureUploader

  validates :content, presence: true,
                      length: { maximum: 50_000 }

  validates :theme, presence: true,
                    length: { minimum: 3, maximum: 100 },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }

  validates :picture, presence: true

  validate :picture_size

  def to_param
    random_link
  end

  private

  def picture_size
    return unless picture.size > 5.megabytes
    errors.add(:picture, 'Файл должен быть меньше, чем 5МБ')
  end
end
```

My uploader:

```
class PictureUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  process resize_to_limit: [600, 300]

  storage :file

  def default_url
    ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("default/no-photo-wide.png")
  end

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end
end
```

And it works well when I run rails server. But I wrote couple of tests, and it really somehow avoid validation and upload picture to my store dir.

My test:

```
let(:large_image) { Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new(File.open(File.join(Rails.root, '/spec/images/large-image.jpg'))) }
    it 'will give error if picture is more then 5mb' do
      post = Post.new(theme: 'foo', content: 'bar)
      post.picture = large_image
      post.save

      puts Post.first.picture

      expect(post.valid?).to be false
    end
```

But result is `true`, not `false`. Can some tell where I made my mistake or suggest any other way to test picture size validation?

Comment: Update `picture_size` and add debug `puts picture.size` to see if image has proper size in tests

Comment: @dziamber Done, it returns 91990 (don't quite understand what that means if actual size of picture is 6,138 mb)

Comment: You are using Paperclip to upload images or any other gem?

Comment: Instead of `picture.size` try `File.size(image_path)`

Comment: @dziamber gem 'carrierwave'

Comment: @dziamber but when I File.size it gives me no file at this location

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to:-Validate-attachment-file-size

Instead of `picture.size` you have to call `picture.file.size.to_f/(1000*1000)`

Comment: But why do I need to change validation method if it works when I run `rails server`, it's only breaks if tests are run?

Comment: I don't know unless you show all code related to this issue. If you receive expected result once then it does not mean that the code works properly in every case

Comment: btw, even when I changed to your answer, it still upload file pass validation, but some additional falled test are appears

Comment: Please paste whole model and test file for it